# Simple example to set initial value of select2 element with Ajax source?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am trying to set the initial value of a [Select2](https://select2.github.io) element that is hooked up to an Ajax data source.

I am using v4 of Select2, and following [the docs](https://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html#removed-initselection), which explain that `initSelection` has been replaced.

I have begun by trying to adapt [the example in the "Loading remote data" section of the Select2 documentation](https://select2.github.io/examples.html). This is my code to set the initial value:

```
var $gitElement = $('.select2');
var option = new Option("yosssi/ejr", '29424443', true, true);
$gitElement.append(option);
$gitElement.trigger('change');
```

I end up with a tag showing `undefined (undefined)`. What am I doing wrong?

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/t4Ltcm0f/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is is your `templateResult` and `templateSelection` functions. The 'repo' argument is an object not containing 'name' and 'full_name' properties, you should use the 'text' property instead.

```
function(repo) { 
    return repo.text || repo.name + ' (' + repo.full_name + ')';
}
```

Working JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/45891w6v/1/